# Has anyone written Ruby code to programmatically modify their DNS?

Tags: ruby, dns

There are a bunch of services (dyndns, nettica, etc.) that offer API's but I'm having trouble with Nettica's and I was just wondering if anyone has a nice gem suggestion for *any* of the DNS services... I'm not set on one or the other.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Chad

Answer (score 0):

This just in, Nettica *does* work as intended, but you need to buy the bulk DNS service in order to enable the AddRecord API call.......  wasn't documented clearly but their support was able to point this out.